# Line break in chemmacros

Tags: line-breaking, chemmacros

I am quite new to LaTeX and I haven't found a solution to my current problem on this site or in the `chemmacros` manual. I have two problems in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all}}
\begin{document}
In the presence of \ch{H2O2}, the chemical reaction of the formation of \ch{K2SiF6:Mn\pch[4]} can be represented by \begin{reaction}
(2 - 2 x) SiO2 + 4 KMnO4 + (20 - 4 x) HF + (4 - 2 x) H2O2 -> 2 K2Si$_{1-x}$Mn$_{x}$F6 + (4 - 2 x) MnO2 + (14 - 4 x) H2O + (7 - 2 x) O2. 
\end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

On the first hand, I would like to introduce a line break (probably after the arrow), since the reaction is too long to fit on one line. I've tried some of the normal line break options but none seam to work.

On the other hand, I had to introduce spaces in the coefficients, using `(2 - 2 x)` instead of `(2-2x)`, to prevent the numeric coefficients to become subscripts. Maybe if this could be fixed without additional spaces, my reaction would fit on one line.

Comment: An isolated `$(2-2x)$` is treated by `chemformula` like a stoichiometric factor…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `reactions` environment, `\\`, and `\notag`. Or just use math environments from `amsmath` and add `\ch{}` for the chemistry. Or probably best: use `amsmath`'s `multline` by adapting it as a reaction environment. Below I also changed your input into the recommended way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\NewChemReaction{multreaction}{multline}

\begin{document}

% using amsmath's `multline':
In the presence of \ch{H2O2}, the chemical reaction of the formation of
\ch{K2SiF6:Mn^4+} can be represented by    
\begin{multreaction}
  $(2-2x)$ SiO2 + 4 KMnO4 + $(20-4x)$ HF + $(4-2x)$ H2O2 -> \\
  2 K2Si_{$1-x$}Mn_{$x$}F6 + $(4-2x)$ MnO2 + $(14-4x)$ H2O + $(7-2x)$ O2. 
\end{multreaction}

% `reactions' with \notag:
\begin{reactions}
  $(2-2x)$ SiO2 + 4 KMnO4 + $(20-4x)$ HF + $(4-2x)$ H2O2 -> \\
  2 K2Si_{$1-x$}Mn_{$x$}F6 + $(4-2x)$ MnO2 + $(14-4x)$ H2O + $(7-2x)$ O2. \notag
\end{reactions}

% `split' in a math equation:
\begin{equation*}
  \refstepcounter{reaction}\usetagform{reaction}
  \begin{split}
    \ch{$(2-2x)$ SiO2 + 4 KMnO4 + $(20-4x)$ HF + $(4-2x)$ H2O2 ->} \\
    \ch{2 K2Si_{$1-x$}Mn_{$x$}F6 + $(4-2x)$ MnO2 + $(14-4x)$ H2O + $(7-2x)$ O2.}
  \end{split}
  \tag{\thereaction}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion,  the `multlined` environment from `mathtools` looks better than `split`.

Comment: @Bernard which is just a variant of the solution I gave ;)

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't even think of posting. It could be worth mentioning this (minor) variant for perfectionists…

Comment: @Bernard quite late but finally added to my answer ;)