# How to break reaction equation in twocolumn document? (chemmacros)

Tags: equations, two-column, chemmacros

I have to write my lab report in a paper-like style where we are forced to use twocolumn style.

I had a look around and found the multicols package does a good job at this because there are a few problems with the native `[twocolumns]` option for the document classes.

I would like to use the `reaction` environment provided by `chemmacros` because I have custom tags for reactions and then it's easier to automatic have separate tags for equations and for reactions. Another upside is that I can have a `\listofreactions` be created for my document.

That is why I do not want to use a `align` or `equation` environment itself.

Currently I looks like this:
[image]

But I would the reactions to either break line (manually or automatically) or be fitted into the columnwidth.

I have tried:

```
\begin{reaction}
  \begin{split}
    Si(OEt)4\, (l) + 4 H2O\, (l) ->[ "cat.\," NaOH ]\\
    Si(OH)4\, (aq) + 4 EtOH\, (l)
  \end{split}
\end{reaction}
and for solution 2 (aluminium in NaOH, named: aluminate solution)
\begin{reaction}
  NaOH\,(aq) + Al\, (s) + 3 H2O\, (l) -> Na[Al(OH)4]\, (aq) + 3/2 
  H2\, (g) "."
\end{reaction}
Therefore we get 
\begin{reaction}
  12 Al(OH)3\, (aq) + 12 Si(OH)4\, (aq) + 12 NaOH\, (aq) -> 
  Na12((AlO2)12(SiO2)12)\, (aq) + 48 H2O\, (l) "."
\end{reaction}
```

Comment: it looks like you can use reactions with \\

Comment: See also: [Line break in chemmacros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376269/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `amsmath` enviroment `multline` for equations in such a situation. `chemmacros` allows you to adapt this environment for reactions by doing:

```
\NewChemReaction{multreaction}{multline}
```

This gives you a much more natural input and no need for `\hspace{...}s` or `\notag`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
% \chemsetup{modules=reactions} % not needed any more in an up to date macros

\NewChemReaction{multreaction}{multline}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{multreaction}
    Si(OEt)4\lqd{} + 4 H2O\lqd{} ->[ "cat.~" NaOH ]\\
    Si(OH)4\aq{} + 4 EtOH\lqd
  \end{multreaction}
  and for solution 2 (aluminium in NaOH, named: aluminate solution)
  \begin{multreaction}
    NaOH\aq{} + Al\lqd{} + 3 H2O\lqd{} -> \\
    Na[Al(OH)4]\aq{} + 3/2 H2\gas{} "."
  \end{multreaction}
  Therefore we get 
  \begin{multreaction}
    12 Al(OH)3\aq{} + 12 Si(OH)4\aq{} + \\
    12 NaOH\aq{} -> \\
    Na12((AlO2)12(SiO2)12)\aq{} + 48 H2O\lqd{} "."
  \end{multreaction}
  \lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the example above I also added `\lqd`, `\aq`, and `\gas` for the phase identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

a solution with little manual alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
        Si(OEt)4\, (l) + 4 H2O\, (l) "\hspace{5cm}" \notag \\
         ->[ "cat.\," NaOH ] Si(OH)4\, (aq) + 4 EtOH\, (l)
\end{reactions}
and for solution 2 (aluminium in NaOH, named: aluminate solution)
\begin{reaction}
    NaOH\,(aq) + Al\, (s) + 3 H2O\, (l) -> Na[Al(OH)4]\, (aq) + 3/2 
    H2\, (g) "."
\end{reaction}
Therefore we get 
\begin{reactions}
    12 Al(OH)3\, (aq) + 12 Si(OH)4\, (aq) + 12 NaOH\, (aq) "\hspace{2cm}" \notag \\
    -> Na12((AlO2)12(SiO2)12)\, (aq) + 48 H2O\, (l) "."
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A reaction in four lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        Therefore we get 
        \begin{reactions}
            12 Al(OH)3\, (aq) + 12 Si(OH)4\, (aq) "\hspace{1cm}" \notag \\
            + 12 NaOH\, (aq) -> "\hspace{2cm}" \notag \\
            Na12((AlO2)12(SiO2)12)\, (aq) "\hspace{0.5cm}" \notag \\
            + 48 H2O\, (l) "."
        \end{reactions}
        and for solution 2 (aluminium in NaOH, named: aluminate solution)
        
        \clearpage
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good approach, but unfortunately, your columns are wider than the ones the OP is working with.  And the third reaction will require more than two lines.

Comment: @barbara beeton see edit.

Comment: Much better!  Thanks.